# referencing data from another table without using a join

Tags: foreign-key, relations

Hi all so I have a homework assignment that I am having difficulty understanding. the problem I have been given is this:

*ix.    Referring to the customers and shipping_details tables on the ER, display all data from the customers table but only where the province on the shipping_details table is equal to NS.  Do not use a join for this requirement.*
[image]

So I can complete the question easily enough using a join but I am having difficulty understanding how one can reference another table without using a join. I am trying to use a vector aggregate function but I am very unclear on how to reference a table and a value within a column of that table without using a join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need to return any data from the shipping_details table, you can use a **[semi-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_(%E2%8B%89)(%E2%8B%8A))**, which can be written with either `IN` and a subquery or `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

Examples:

```
-- Using IN --
select c.*
from customers as c
where c.shipping_detail_id IN
  ( select sd.shipping_detail_id
    from shipping_details as sd
    where sd.province = 'NS'
  ) ;


-- Using EXISTS --
select c.*
from customers as c
where EXISTS 
  ( select 1 
    from shipping_details as sd
    where sd.province = 'NS'
      and sd.shipping_detail_id = c.shipping_detail_id    -- correlation
  ) ;
```

Comment: perfect! just had to make a minor change changing customer_id to Shipping_detail_id but that helps a lot! thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, if the FK / connecting attribute (shipping_detail_id) is from customer to to shipping_details, yeah.